# Why ItemsControl does not refreshed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, propertychanged

I have the following xaml:

```xaml
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:CalendarViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="55*" />
        <ColumnDefinition
            Width="27*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <local:UserControlCalendar
        x:Name="ControlCalendar"
        Grid.Column="0">
    </local:UserControlCalendar>
    <ItemsControl
        x:Name="HistoryControl"
        Grid.Column="1"
        Width="210"
        Margin="30,10,0,0"
        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DataTemplate.HistoryItems}"
        ItemsPanel="{StaticResource ItemsPanel.Vertical}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ListHistoryItems, Mode=OneWay}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.Margin" Value="0,10,0,0" />
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    </ItemsControl>
</Grid>
```

When select a date in UserControlCalendar should change the contents of the "HistoryControl". In ViewModel Property ListHistoryItems changed, but ItemsControl in UserControl don't refreshed.
This is ViewModel:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
namespace CustomCalendar
{
  public class CalendarViewModel :  INotifyPropertyChanged
  {
    private ObservableCollection<HistoryItems> _listHistoryItems;
    private DateTime _selectedDate;

    public CalendarViewModel()
    {
    }

    public DateTime SelectedDate
    {
        get { return _selectedDate; }
        set
        {
            _selectedDate = value;
            if (_selectedDate != null)
            {
                ListHistoryItems = new ObservableCollection<HistoryItems>(GetHistoryItems(_selectedDate));
            }
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<HistoryItems> ListHistoryItems
    {
        get { return _listHistoryItems; }
        set
        {
            _listHistoryItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ListHistoryItems");
        }
    }

    protected virtual void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  }
}
```

The problem is that Event PropertyChanged are always null.
Why? 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Is `SelectedDate` ever set?  I don't see it bound anywhere in the View.

Comment: @CharlesMager In UserControlCalendar in Codebehind is a function that sets the SelectedDate on the select date. I  need a SelectedDate only as a parameter to the function GetHistoryItems()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. To transfer SelectedDate of the UserControlCalendar in the MainWindow, I have created in UserControlCalendar new ViewModel. Therefore, nothing worked. Now I removed that object, and all works fine. Now there's another question, how to transfer the SelectedDate in the ViewModel. I think the use of Prism and EventAggregator.

Comment: Transfer what? Ve more specific

Comment: UserControlCalendar has a Property SelectedDate<DateTime>. I need transfer (send) this Propety to another ViewModel.

Answer (score 1):

ObservableCollection automatically notifyi UI if Collection changes. If the HistoryModel properties changes, yhen you need to call RaisePropertyChanged for that Property to notfyi UI. And if you make new ObservableCollection via new keyword, you need to refresh it to control.ItemsSource.

Also those controls that should show value of historymodel, use binding path=propertyname

Comment: I have ItemsControl that has ItemsSource. ItemsSource has Binding to ListHistoryItems. I'm getting a new ListHistoryItems, that is a ObservableCollection, which automatically calls the function RaiseProretyChanged   
        
            _listHistoryItems = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("ListHistoryItems");
        but Event PropertyChanged is NULL. Therefore, the notification UI does not occur.